# Why are buttons not working in Angular 13

Tags: angular-material, angular13

I have an Angular 13 project that is working except I can't seem to get Angular Material applying.  I have been able to get it to work in other projects.
I installed Angular Material with the command:

```
ng add @angular/material@13.0.2
```

I see the "@angular/material/button" folder under node_modules.

I have the "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" reference  in both style locations in angular.json.

So I created a file called "material.module.ts" for the angular-material module.  Here is the code for that:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { MatButtonModule } from "@angular/material/button";

const features = [MatButtonModule]

@NgModule({
    imports: [features],
    exports: [features]
})
export class MaterialFeatures { }
```

Then I registered the Material Feature Module in the root module, app.module.ts.

I have this import statement at the top:

```
import { MaterialFeatures } from './material.module';
```

And I list the Material Module in the NgModule imports section:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, ModelModule, ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule, MaterialFeatures,
    // Do I need these?
    CoreModule, MessageModule, routing, BrowserAnimationsModule],
  providers: [TermsGuard, LoadGuard],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

So then I have a component named table.component.html.
All the buttons were bootstrap and I am attempting to switch them over to angular material.

Here is the code for a Delete button and Edit button.
The Edit button still has bootstrap classes btn, btn-warning, and btn-sm.
For the Delete button I have replaced the bootstrap classes with the mat-flat-button and color="accent" attributes.

```
<td class="text-center">
    <button mat-flat-button color="accent"
      (click)="deleteProduct(item.id)">
        Delete
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" 
      [routerLink]="['/form', 'edit', item.id]">
        Edit
    </button>
</td>
```

In the screenshot below you can see that Material-Angular is not being applied to the delete button.

[image]

One other funny thing going on is I have this rule in styles.css:

```
button.mat-flat-button {
    margin: 2px;
}
```

and it is not being applied either.  As you can see above there is no margin or spacing being applied to the Delete button.

I am getting no errors in the console window.

I have ended the terminal and restarted with ng serve several times but it doesn't fix the problem.  I even trashed the project and started over and ended up in the same place.  I'm at a loss.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what could be going on?
I must be missing something really small.